# Why would I be getting TPS lag spikes every 30 seconds on a single player local client world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

I am using the AtLauncher with a modded Thaumcraft based world and keep getting a lag spike every 30 seconds that basically stops the world and it rushes to catch up. Turing on the Lagometer it shows it as TICK lag which I don't get since I am playing local on my machine not on a server.

Does anyone know a setting that might cause this?

I am not running Thaumcraft machines constantly (they are too noisy) but I do have a fair number of golems. That is not my first thought for an cause because the golems are pretty random and the spike is fairly constant at 30 seconds. Event if I pull up the options menu and all mobs stop and time stands still the Lagometer still runs in the back ground and I still see the spikes.

**Mod List:**
forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1230-universal
LibSandstone-1.0.0
CodeChickenLib-1.7.10-1.1.1.99-universal
Deconstruction-Table-1.7.10
Reliquary-1.2
Carpenter's Blocks v3.3.4.1
Chisel-1.7.10-1.5.6
DeadlyWorld-1.7.10-1.0.2
twilightforest-1.7.10-2.3.2
Thaumcraft-1.7.10-4.2.3.5
Baubles-1.7.10-1.0.1.10
CodeChickenCore-1.7.10-1.0.4.29-universal
NotEnoughItems-1.7.10-1.0.3.74-universal
statues-1.7.10-2.1.4
AsieLib-1.7.10-0.3.8
Waila-1.5.5-1.7.10
EnchantView-v4.0.4
ThebombzenAPI-v2.4.1-mc1.7.2
OptiFine_1.7.10_HD_B5
Automagy-1.7.10-0.22.1
[image: Single player TICK lag screen shot]

Comment: Arguing form the point that you have mods installed, I am pretty sure it's one of the mods kind of glitching out and slowing down your already hard working PC. Also: Tick lag is possible on the client side, too, because you generally create a local server to which you connect when you load up a single player world.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Comment: It was to better understand the activity of the server. I could begin to use this question to trouble shoot without an understand of what would cause such a spike. However, I have abandon this minecraft world because it became unplayable and I have no problems with this being closed. If I need to do that, I am currently not aware how, but if you will pass that information to me I will do so,.

Answer (score 1):

The game, even on singleplayer, is separated into a client and server. This means that the server can lag behind (tick lag) without the client experiencing an FPS drop.

This is likely caused by what appears to be a fairly extensive Thaumcraft setup, and the server being unable to keep up with the processing. Other mods or events in the world may also be contributing, although we'd need a world file and list of mods (F3 says you have 20) to work out what else could be causing the lag.

Changing graphical settings will most likely not help. You can try reducing the number of loaded chunks, shutting off machines and mechanisms when you do not need them, or uninstalling unnecessary mods.

Comment: Added the mode list and I already don't use the thaumcraft setup continuously. It just too noisy. But the lag spikes are like clock work whether the machines are running or not.